# Shopware 6 JEST test with vue test-utils: infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuex, vue-test-utils, shopware6

**Vue** 2.6.14
**Vuex** 3.1.1
**Vue test-utils** 1.3.0
**Jest** 29.3

The code works well in `dev environment` but on the **JEST component test with vue test-utils** the code running into **an infinite update loop in a component render function**.

my-component/**index.js**

```
const { Component } = Shopware;

Component.register('my-component', {
    template: '<sw-number-field :value="computedComponentPurchaseSum(0)"></sw-number-field>',

    inject: [
        'repositoryFactory'
    ],

    computed: {

        computedComponentPurchaseSum() {

            return (i) => {
                Shopware.State.commit('MyPluginStore/setLoading', ['productComponents', true]) // caused the error
                return 15;
            }

        }
    }
})
```

The error appears by `Shopware.State.commit('MyPluginStore/setLoading', ['productComponents', true])`, disabled the test is green.

store.js

```
...
mutations: {
    setLoading(state, params) {
        console.log('hello')
    }
}
```

**EDit #1**
error output

```
    Expected test not to call console.error().

    If the error is expected, test for it explicitly by mocking it out using jest.spyOn(console, 'error').mockImplementation() and test that the warning occurs.

    [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.
    
    found in
    
    ---> <MyComponent>
           <Root>
        at console.captureMessage [as error] ([...]/node_modules/jest-fail-on-console/index.js:56:25)
        at warn ([...]/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:621:15)
        at flushSchedulerQueue ([...]/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4319:9)
        at Array.<anonymous> ([...]/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1985:12)
        at flushCallbacks ([...]/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:1911:14)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

      at flushUnexpectedConsoleCalls ([...]/node_modules/jest-fail-on-console/index.js:40:13)
      at Object.<anonymous> ([...]/node_modules/jest-fail-on-console/index.js:95:7)
```

**Questions**

- How to debug this error?
- What is the error reason?
- How to fix it?

Comment: Probably the State.commit triggers the computation somehow and this causes the endless loop. I guess in your final code you will fetch the data from remote in the computed property, that's why you need the `setLoading`? Can you restructure so that the data is loaded differently?

Comment: Maybe https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/vue/async-computed is helpful ... I think you should load the data when you parameters change - hard to say without additional context - but not inside of the computed property.

Comment: @Alex thx. There is no (ajax)-request behind. It is just a js-setter inside the store...

Comment: So why do you need setLoading then?

Comment: @Alex in current context it's just a dummy function for test purpose, i can rename it into setDumm(), it's the same

Comment: But do you need to commit the state? Because that seems to be the problem, I believe. What's the real task you want to carry out in this line?

Comment: Yes, a attribute is set in a component for its template and the use case is update this attribute in another component. And as i understand, the store is exactly created for this goal.